Angular update Tab A from Tab B using a service
I'm a Jr talking about Angular, I have a question:
Context: A Teacher can own multiple Students.

Requirement # 1.- They want to be able to open a new tab from the Teacher Admin page for each Student. This is working
Requirement # 2.- When you click on Save on one of the Students Admin, the Teachter Admin page should refreshed.

Is requirement 2 technically possible?
Student Api Service
export class StudentApiService extends BaseService {
protected endPoint = "student/student";

private lastStudentUpdate$$: Subject<StudentUpdate> = new Subject<StudentUpdate>();
public lastStudentUpdate$: Observable<StudentUpdate> = this.lastStudentUpdate$$.asObservable();

getStudent(id: number) : Observable<any>
{
    return this.get( {id: id});
}

getStudents(teacherId: number): Observable<any> {
    return this.get({ teacherId: teacherId });
}

createPendingStudent(model: StudentCreate) :  Observable<any>
{
    return this.post(model);
}

updateStudent(model: StudentUpdate) : Observable<any>
{
    this.lastStudentUpdate$$.next(model);
    return this.put(model);
}

}
teacher-wizard.component.ts
@Component({


 selector: 'app-teacher-wizard',
  templateUrl: './teacher-wizard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./teacher-wizard.component.scss']
})
export class TeacherWizardComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  id: number;
  lastStudentUpdate$: Observable<StudentUpdate>;
  
  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private studentApiService: StudentApiService,
    private router: Router
  ) { }
  
  checkParams(params: ParamMap) {
    const teacherId = 'teacherId';
    if (!params.has(teacherId)) {
      return;
    }
    this.id = +params.get(teacherId);
  }

  ngOnInit() {

    let sub = this.route.parent.url.pipe(
      withLatestFrom(this.route.parent.paramMap)
    ).subscribe(([url, paramMap]) => {
      this.checkParams(paramMap);
      this.getRoutes();
    });
    this.subs.push(sub);
    this.subs.push(routingEventSub);
    this.lastStudentUpdate$ = this.studentApiService.lastStudentUpdate$
    .pipe(startWith(undefined));

    this.lastStudentUpdate$.subscribe((x)=>{
      console.log(x);
    })
  }

    getRoutes() {
    const cr: Routes = this.route.snapshot.routeConfig.children.filter(x => x.path.length > 0);
    this.childRoutes = cr.map(x => (
      {
        exact: !x.children,
        display: x.data.display,
        path: x.path,
        iconClass: x.data?.iconClass,
        tooltip: x.data?.tooltip,
        component: x.component,
        displayOnlyOnRoute: x.data?.displayOnlyOnRoute === true,
        isExclusiveOperation: x.data?.isExclusiveOperation === true,
      }));
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.formService.destroyFormGroup(this.formGroup);
    this.subs.forEach(sub => sub.unsubscribe());
  }
}

student-wizard.component.ts
@Component({
selector: 'student-wizard',
  templateUrl: './student-wizard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./student-wizard.component.scss'],
})
export class StudentWizardComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  id: number;
  student: string;
  private subs: Subscription[] = [];
  formGroup: UntypedFormGroup;
  childRoutes: Array<any>;
  lastStudentUpdate$: Observable<StudentUpdate>;

  constructor(
    private _router: Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private studentApiService: StudentApiService,
    private formService: StudentEditFormService
  ) { }

  checkParams(params: ParamMap) {
    const studentId = 'studentId';
    if (!params.has(studentId)) {
      return;
    }
    this.id = +params.get(studentId);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.currentlySaving = false;
    const sub1 = this.route.params.pipe(
      withLatestFrom(this.route.parent.paramMap),
      switchMap(([url, paramMap]) => {
        this.checkParams(paramMap);
        this.getRoutes();
        return this.studentApiService.getStudent(this.id)
      }),
      switchMap(x => {
        this.student = x.student;
        return this.formService.createFormGroup(x)
      })
    ).subscribe(fg => {
      this.formGroup = fg;
      new FormDirtyCheckerService(fg);
    });

    this.subs = [sub1];

    this.lastStudentUpdate$ = this.studentApiService.lastStudentUpdate$
    .pipe(startWith(undefined));

    this.lastStudentUpdate$.subscribe((x)=>{
      console.log(x);
    })
  }
ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.subs.forEach(s => s.unsubscribe());
    this.formService.destroyFormGroup(this.formGroup);
  }

  getLastSegment() {
    return window.location.pathname.split('/').slice(-1)[0];
  }

  save($event) {
    this.doSave(false);
  }

  saveAndBack($event) {
    this.doSave(true);
  }

  doSave(returnToAdmin) {
    if (!this.formGroup.dirty) {
      //No changes detected;
      return;
    };
    this.currentlySaving = true;
    return this.studentApiService.updateStudent(model);
  }


  hasWarnings(formGroup : UntypedFormGroup) {
    if (!formGroup?.controls) return false;
    const found = Object.keys(formGroup.controls).find(key  => {
      const ctrl : AbstractControlExtended = formGroup.get(key);
      return ctrl.warnings !== undefined && ctrl.warnings !== null;
    });
    return found !== undefined;
  }
 }
}

with this example code I have the next behavior:

I Open Teacher Admin Page, I have listed the Students, I can Open New Tabs for each Students

I added an observable to Student Api Service (lastStudentUpdate)

When I click save in Student Admin Page I do see in Student Admin Page console:
undefined
lastUpdatedStudent info
undefined

I dont see lastUpdatedStudent info in Teacher Admin Page Console, only an undefined due subscription startwith
undefined


any idea?
I'm using

Visual Studio Code
NodeJS 20.15.1
Angular CLI: 16.2.11
Node: 22.7.0 (Unsupported)
Package Manager: npm 9.5.0
Angular: 16.2.12
typescript 4.9.5


When opened in a new browser tab a new and independent instance of your application is created. See this article for advice on this issue: https://medium.com/@md.mollaie/mastering-cross-tab-communication-in-angular-with-broadcastchannel-api-0e15ccef75bf
Also, here is a link for the BroadcastChannel API: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BroadcastChannel

That is just what I needed!! Thanks!!

you can use localStorage or sessionStorage for this when you click on the save button set the flag in storage to true and listen storage event in first component and after listening set the flag false or remove the item use this code in teacher admin.
Note- teacher and student admin should be form same domain
window.addEventListener('storage', event => {   if (event.key === 'refreshFirstTab' && event.newValue === 'true') {
    // Refresh the page
    location.reload();
    // Clear the flag
    localStorage.removeItem('refreshFirstTab');   } });


I had to modify your recommendation using renderer2, DOCUMENT to add an script tag const s = this.renderer2.createElement('script'); s.type = 'text/javascript';  s.text = 'script text';   in teacher to reload it if localStorage.getItem("studentReady"); Then another script tag in student to set when saving student localStorage.setItem("studentReady", Math.random().toString()); and calling manually the localstorage event as follows window.dispatchEvent( new Event('storage') );
